# How to extract words from parentheses in C language?

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok

I am trying to extract words from a string like this:

```
(octopus kitten) (game cake) (soccer football)
```

I attempted doing this with the help of `strtok` (I do `strcpy` just for not modifying the original token/string, also used `memcpy`, but it does the same in my case).

*Main function:*

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  char row[] = "(octopus kitten) (game cake) (soccer football)";
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok(row, "(");

  while (pch != NULL) {

    pch[strcspn(pch, ")")] = '\0';
    print_word(pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, "(");

  }

  return 0;
}
```

*Function for getting and printing each word:*

```
void get_and_print_word(char str[]) {

  char r[4000];

// for not modifying the original string
  strcpy(r, str);

  char * c = strtok(r, " ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    printf("%s\n", c);
    c = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
}
```

It works absolutely fine with a first iteration, but after `pch` starts to point to another adress of memory (but it should point to the adress of letter "g").

It works absolutely fine (it's just printing string within the brackets) if we remove `get_and_print_word(pch)`:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  char row[] = "(octopus kitten) (game cake) (soccer football)";
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok(row, "(");

  while (pch != NULL) {

    pch[strcspn(pch, ")")] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, "(");

  }

  return 0;
}
```

But that's not what I want to do, I need to get each word, not just a string of two words and space between them.

Using `pch = strtok(NULL, " )(")` is also not appropriate in my case, cause I need to store each pair of words (each word, of couse, should be a separate string) in some individual
`struct`, so I definitely need this function.

How to solve this issue and why it works like this?

Comment: Read more about [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and the first chapters of the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). If that is allowed to you, consider using [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/). Think also of strings with strange letters, like `Être ou ne pas être`. In 2021, [UTF-8 is everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: Maybe you could code your [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). Define your grammar in [EBNF notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) -with pencil and paper. Be aware of [pushdown automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

Comment: Are you supposed to parse `(a (very (strange)) cat) (eating a (piece of cake))` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, I just need to parse pairs of words within parentheses in a way I've written

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Strings should be in English letters, so we won't face any strange letters.

Comment: You need to document on paper what you should parse and accept, and what you should reject. One single string is never enough to define a language. Is `be_one` or `and/or` a single word, or two of them? Use also the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger

Comment: You could study for inspiration some source code from [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) - it is coded in C and can parse your example

Comment: Your basic problem is the space(s) outside of the parenthesis.  Which brings up the question, what do you want to do with an input like `(a b) c d (e f)`?  Should that give just two strings (`a b` and `e f`) or 4 or something else?  What about nested parentheses?  What about mixed things with no space before the `(`?

Comment: @ChrisDodd No nested parentheses, just 2 words in a parentheses. For instance, (soccer football) (game joke). I should get strings: "soccer" "football" in one iteration and "game" "joke" in another

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I just need to parse this simple type of string, there will be no nested parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use regular expression :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int err;
   regex_t preg;
   const char *str_request = argv[1];
   const char *str_regex = argv[2];
   err = regcomp (&preg, str_regex, REG_EXTENDED);
   if (err == 0) {
      int match;
      size_t nmatch = 0;
      regmatch_t *pmatch = NULL;
      nmatch = preg.re_nsub;
      pmatch = malloc (sizeof (*pmatch) * nmatch);
      char *buffer;
      if (pmatch) {
         buffer = (char *) str_request;
         match = regexec (&preg, buffer, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
         while (match == 0) {
            char *found = NULL;
            size_t size ;
            int start, end;
            start = pmatch[0].rm_so;
            end = pmatch[0].rm_eo;
            size = end - start;
            found = malloc (sizeof (*found) * (size + 1));
            if (found) {
               strncpy (found, &buffer[start], size);
               found[size] = '\0';
               printf ("found : %s\n", found);
               free (found);
            }
            //searching next occurence
            match = regexec (&preg, (buffer += end), nmatch, pmatch, 0);
         }
         regfree (&preg);
         free (pmatch);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}

[puppet@damageinc regex]$ ./regex "(octopus kitten) (game cake) (soccer football)" "([a-z]+)"
found : octopus
found : kitten
found : game
found : cake
found : soccer
found : football
```